# AspNetCore JWT Authentication Without "iat" in token header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to configure an authentication in some application that will consume the login validation from another system. Basically, I get a token with the users information, and I have to map it to my database, because the user it was already authenticated. We're doing it with using jwt tokens.

So here's the problem:

The token I'm getting doesn't have "iat" field, and AspNetCore seems to reject the token without that field.

Is there a way to configure the authentication to ignore that field?

Here is the token structure:

#### TOKEN - HEADER

```
{
  "alg": "HS512"
}
```

#### TOKEN - BODY

```
{
  "sub": [mysub],
  "user": { ... },
  "exp": [timestamp]
}
```

And here's the configuration:

```
...
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** An earlier version of this answer mixed up `iat` and `nbf`. The answer has been rewritten accordingly.

---

I tried reproducing your issue in an empty project, and *was* successfully able to validate a token with the structure you outlined in your question (so without the `iat` claim).

Setup I used to get this to work:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        SignatureValidator = (t, p) => new JwtSecurityToken(t)
                    };
            });
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

```
[Authorize]
[Route("debug")]
public class DebugAuthController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() => Ok(User.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "user").Value);
}
```

I used the following token for testing: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJteXN1YmplY3QiLCJ1c2VyIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJTdGFja092ZXJmbG93In0sImV4cCI6MTU5MDk5NzMyNn0.FVFl6gDYOrmzj7_6OqHPTxU3mfQWs864u7fBLM5ThuM`

It's worth double-checking to see if you're calling both `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` in `ConfigureServices`, and that you're calling them in that order.

---

**Note:** Sample code provided disables virtually all validation checks on the JWT for testing purposes. Do not use this code as-is unless you know what you're doing!

Comment: I tried to debug this function, and wihtout the ```iat``` field the code doens't even get in that function

Comment: I mixed up `iat` and `nbf` in my original answer. Updated with a minimal reproduction of a setup that works for me.

Comment: The bug was elsewhere but i'll share here. It turns out the database which was holding the secret to encrypt my token was defined to have a ```maxlenght = 100``` and my secret had something about 120 chars. So the database was truncating my secret. Yet sometimes the token was validated, and I never got a message of ```Invalid secret``` or something like that.